# Effective Controlling of Continous Servo Motor

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor, servo, software

I have difficulty in controlling a ***MG995 continuous motor***. For I know I can control the speed of the motor as writing servo1.write(p) , where the value of p changes the speed of the motor. When the value of p is set to 90 then the motor stops ,whereas 0 and 180 values allows it to move in the top speed in C.W and Anti C.W direction respectively.
...........** I had difficulty in writing a code where I can rotate the servo motor for 180 degrees then rotating back again to 0 and whenever my ultrasonic sensor finds any object the servo should stop at that point for further action. ** ........
*(I think this value could be useful :Operating speed: 0.2 s/60º (4.8 V), 0.16 s/60º (6 V))*

Comment: You want to rotate at any speed that you want, or you want to rotate to any angle that you want?

Comment: I want to rotate at a specific angle .

Comment: Then you need some form of feedback from the motor's shaft to know what angle it is at. Normally if you want an angle then you don't want a continuous rotation servo.

Comment: I have a feeling that by using time functions we can rotate it at any angle .If my calculations are correct then for every angle it takes 3 milliseconds to turn.Well I don't know if we can use this

Comment: You can get an approximation, but it will drift over time. That's a "nominal" speed, not taking into account acceleration and deceleration and variances in manufacturing.

Comment: what are you trying to do ... your question says nothing about the end goal of your project

Comment: I am trying to make a Radar type mechanism which will sweep to a particular angle and help the ultrasonic sonic sensor to locate an object .....

Comment: According to your project description, it sounds like you need a typical non-continuous servo motor - one that rotates to a specific angle. Do you actually need rotational speed control? You *could* do both with a continuous, speed-controlled servo but it is only going to servo on rotational speed; you'll need to do the control on angle with a shaft encoder and software.

Comment: Initially I wanted a typical non-continuous servo but instead amazon got me a continuous servo even when the description had clearly mentioned of a non-continuous servo.

Comment: Have you been able to rotate the servo to a position, stop and go back to the initial position? Could you try doing it with the "servo1.write" function and the delay function (or using a busy-loop)?